# How to restart pc when the pc losses connection

Tags: windows, restart

I need to restart a windows pc when it losses internet connection for more than 2 minutes. Is there a way to do that? I have no idea what should I do. Any help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is always a way. Break your problem into sub-problems. How will you determine if you're connected? How will you trigger a restart? Those are both smaller issues you can research that should be fairly easy compared to the problem as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could register a Windows task to check internet connection "On an event". After that it's possible get an action like restart, shutdown, etc. Go to Panel Control => System Tools and then make some like this: 
[Windows Task](https://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection)

Comment: Thanks man, helped me a lot!